# Performance choice: DML vs DDL trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ddl

I have a table [A] with some columns and a PK. Each time an `update` is performed on [A], I want to keep the old and the new values of the rows that were updated in another table, [Alog]. So I have some triggers to do that.

In order to only keep the updated columns, I use `columns_updated()` on an update trigger. But what should I check it against, for better performance?

1. One logic is to do the bit "decoding" and compare it with sys.columns.column_id. What I don't like in this solution is the reading of the sys schema on each row update
2. Another logic is to put bit mask literals for each column in the code (eg:

   column4 = case when @columns_updated & 0x08 > 0 then column4 end
   )
   This has the danger that columns might have their column_id changed, so I'll have to make a DDL trigger on the database, which re-creates the trigger code if the table is altered. What I don't like about this solution is that the database trigger is fired on every ddl statement.

How does reading sys.columns on each table row compare with firing a ddl trigger?

Comment: Yes. I might incorporate that in the code, but it's a separate matter.

Comment: columns_updated() doesn't work as most people expect.....

Comment: If the objective is to keep history, use a Temporal table. It's much simpler

Comment: We don not have the luxury of sql16+ - only features, it must work on 2012

Answer (score -1):

the triggers are slow in SQL Server.

You can use the following code:

```
Update [A]
Set [COLUMN_1] = NEW_VALUE
OUTPUT 
--These are the columns with the old value.
deleted.[COLUMN_1],deleted.[COLUMN_2],deleted.[COLUMN_3],
-- These are the columns with the new value.
--> inserted.[COLUMN_1],inserted.[COLUMN_2],inserted.[COLUMN_3]
INTO [B]
Where [COLUMN_1]=OLD_VALUE
```

Comment: I do not have control over original statements, they can be performed by a variety of sources, like ad hoc queries, procedures and applications.

Comment: "the triggers are slow in SQL Server" - That statement is incorrect. Triggers might be slower than actions enforced by constraints, BUT slow triggers are created by the inexperienced, doing inappropriate or expensive actions in them.